# Setting hotkey for application menu

Tags: release-loki

I want to make it so when it press the windows key on my keyboard the applications menu pops up. How do i do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you press both Windows keys together? When you press either one?

Comment: Oops, i didn't see the type i meant windows **key** not **keys**

Answer (score 2):

To set the Windows key use:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['Super_L']"`

If you don't like the change (as I), you can reset it with:

`gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu`

I recommend you to check this [tutorial](https://mylinuxevolution.wordpress.com/elementary-os-loki-post-installation-tutorials/), it has some neat tweaks for Loki.